# Is Linq Select asynchronous inside a separate function?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Here's my situation:

I have an C# API Get function, inside which contains a global variable (to be returned in the end) and several functions, as below:

```
public Dictionary<...,...> Get()
{
   getDataFromLinQ(); //inside this, there is a LinQ select 

   processRawLinQData(); //this processes raw data, and store it into dictResult

   return dictResult;
}
```

If i am writing in this way, it will return no result, as it seems that it doesn't wait the LinQ to finish select first.

However, if I am writing this way:

```
public Dictionary<...,...> Get()
{
  //execute linq directly, but not inside a separate function
  IQueryable<table1> linQResult = from t1 in db.table1
                     where t1...
                     select t1;

  foreach(table1 x in linQResult)
  {
     //do processing and store in some variables.
  }

  processRawLinQData();

  return dictResult;
}
```

This will work. But why?

Is LinQ select an Asynchronous method or it behaves differently if i put it inside another function?

P.S.: 
1. I prefer method 1 (using function) as the codes are more readable.
2. I notice this scenario on the development/live server. In my local computer, both are working.

Comment: What does `getDataFromLinQ()` look like? Are you actually enumerating the query anywhere?

Comment: `getDataFromLinQ()`  //inside this, there is a LinQ select .If here you call a `.ToList()` (enumerating) then there is your problem

Comment: is `getDataFromLinQ` an `async` method? If so, you have to do `await getDataFromLinQ()`

Comment: @Lee I have added the code in the question (second part - directly execute linq). Basically just some query linq select.

Comment: @RazvanDumitru Can you elaborate a little more? Do you mean .ToList() is an aysnchronous process?

Comment: @AD.Net That's my curiosity. It is just a normal select (plus some synchronous code such as foreach loop). Ya my current workaround is to move out the code from the function (or like what you said, put an await). But i am curious, is linq select an async process? But if so, why it isn't when i take the code out from the function?

Comment: I think you're not actually executing the query. The 2nd example works because `foreach` forces the execution of your query and you have the result. So you should actually execute your query by `ToList()` in the first method

Comment: @AD.Net i did T.T... So your point is, as long as `ToList()` is executed, the code would be executed normally.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is lazy ... if you don't use it, or use a `ToList()` to force a result, it might not be called if not needed.

So, you have a method call ... it goes in, have some linq, says ..I'll call it if I need, and goes back.

Then other method assumes your query finished and returned something ... but you're in a whole different place now.

I'm not sure I'm conveying my point ... but maybe it'll help you out a bit.

Comment: i think to some extent i understand what you are trying to say. But is the case "might not be called if not needed" only taking place in a method call? As if it is placed in the main function (Get()), it seems to be called all the time.